# STS workspace getting corrupted causing STS not able to start

Tags: shutdown, workspace

STS workspace getting corrupted causing STS not able to start.

I had STS workspace opened for my application. For some reasons the machine got shutdown, causing the STS not able to start later. It goes in to a hanging state, and stuck on some STS GUI plugin loading problem.

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use a fresh copy of sts, your workspace will remain intact.
Or try running `eclipsec.exe` instead of `sts.exe`.